# How to mount a local directory to a remote directory on a remote server

Tags: 12.04

How can I mount a local directory in my local Ubuntu machine to a remote directory on a different server?

i.e. is If ~/local_directory/bin/exec , it will execute the exec in the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use SSHFS, a tool that uses SSH to enable mounting of a remote filesystem on a local machine.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS for full instructions.

You will need to install and run an SSH server on your local machine and install SSHFS on your server.